# Are material spell components consumed during casting or during preparation?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spell-components

Next to spells in the PHB spell list are lists of components, some of which are material. When specified, material components are expended:

> **Arcane Lock**
>   Components: V, S, M (gold dust worth at least 25 gp, which the spell consumes)

What I'm asking is exactly **when** those components are consumed. Is it when you **cast** the spell, or when you **prepare** it?

Comment: Keep in mind that not all spellcasters prepare spells in 5e.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Components are consumed when casting (if applicable).

The Player's Handbook has this to say on materials when casting spells:

> If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each **casting** of the spell. *(PHB, 203)*

Emphasis mine.

Components are consumed when the spell is *cast*, not when it is prepared.

Answer (score 1):

## The components are consumed when the spell is cast.

PHB pg. 203

> If a spell states that a material component is consumed by the spell, the caster must provide this component for each **casting** of the spell. (emphasis mine)